# Adding rows to a column in Ext.net

Tags: ext.net, gridpanel

I´m trying to add specific rows into a column in ext.net taking into account, that the data for the column´s rows is stored into a table in database (oracle) i bring from database a cursor with the data. but in the ASPX.CS how can i set it properly?

here is what i had made:

```
[DirectMethod]
        public void loadColumnsHeaders ()
        {
            DataTable dtSalas = respuesta.CroomNames();
            //this.loadColumnsHeaders(dtSalas);

            foreach (DataRow dataRow in dtSalas.Rows)
            {
                ModelField modelField = new ModelField()
                {
                    Name = dataRow["SALA_ID"].ToString()
                };
                this.GPdisponibilidad.GetStore().AddField(modelField, 0);  //gpDISPONIBILIDAD = IS THE GRIDPANEL ID
                Column column1 = new Column()
                {
                    Text = dataRow["SALA_NOMBRE"].ToString(), //sala_nombre = name of a column from database, same for sala_id.
                    DataIndex = dataRow["SALA_ID"].ToString()
                };
                this.GPdisponibilidad.AddColumn(column1);

            }
        }
```

in the previous code i had created a dynamic column fromthe database, but in this case i need to create rows/registers..

appreciate help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the database cursor just to get a page per time, use a grid pager (http://examples4.ext.net/#/GridPanel/Paging_and_Sorting/DirectMethod/) to load the data. The load is not cumulative so it gets lightweight for the client browser.

If you want to arbitrarily bring new records to the grid from the database, you can use DataReader and append the new records like done in this example: http://examples4.ext.net/#/GridPanel/Miscellaneous/Add_Mode/